# Size of subspaces of $\mathbb{F}_p^n$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, combinatorics

If $\mathbb{F}_q$ is the field of characteristic $q$ then $\mathbb{F}_q^n$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_q^n$ of dimension $n$.

It is apparently true that if $V\subset \mathbb{F}_q^n$ is a subspace of dimension $m$ then $V$ has exactly $q^m$ elements but I can't find a proof of this. It is easy to check if $m=1$ or $m=n$ (: but even the case $m=2$ is eluding me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $V\subseteq\mathbb{F}_q^n$ is a subspace, it is a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_q$ in its own right. If $\dim_{\mathbb{F}_q}(V)=m$, then $V\simeq\mathbb{F}_q^m$, since vector spaces over a given field are determined by their dimension up to isomorphism. Hence $\#V=\#\mathbb{F}_q^m=q^m$.

Answer (score 2):

If $V$ is an $m$-dimensional subspace of an $n$-dimensional vector space $W$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$, then we can choose a basis $\{\beta_1,\dots,\beta_n\}$ for $W$ such that $\{\beta_1,\dots,\beta_m\}$ is a basis for $V$.

Using coordinates with respect to this basis, we can identify $V$ with the subspace
$$ \{(c_1,\dots,c_m,0,\dots,0):c_1,\dots,c_m\in\mathbb{F}_q\}$$ 
of $\mathbb{F}_q^n$, and this subspace has $q^m$ elements because there are $q$ choices for each of $c_1,\dots,c_m$.